# c++ exception are not caught by catch(exception type)

Tags: c++, exception

Here is a piece of code that I have my exception in:

```
try {
        hashTable->lookup(bufDescTable[clockHand].file, bufDescTable[clockHand].pageNo, dummyFrame);
    }
    catch (HashNotFoundException *e) {

    }
    catch (HashNotFoundException &e) {

    }
    catch (HashNotFoundException e) {

    }
    catch (...) {

    }
```

Exception is generated within hashTable->lookup like that:

```
throw HashNotFoundException(file->filename(), pageNo);
```

Here is hashTable-lookup method signature

```
 void BufHashTbl::lookup(const File* file, const PageId pageNo, FrameId &frameNo)
```

Exception escalates to top level like it's nobody's business.

I am using Mac(Lion) and Xcode(g++ for compiler)

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the function signature of "lookup" function. Specifically check if there are restrictions on the kinds of exceptions it can throw.

Comment: Added it to the question. Within .cpp there are no restrictions.

Comment: Can you produce a SSCE? http://sscce.org/ Also its probably worth mentioning what compiler & OS you're using.

Comment: Trimmed down the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We really need a complete example / further info to diagnose this for you.

For example the following version of the code compiles and works for me, outputing `HashNotFoundException &`

Note the code has some minor changes from your original, but they should not be material.

However it does generate the following warning:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:42: warning: exception of type ‘HashNotFoundException’ will be caught
example.cpp:38: warning:    by earlier handler for ‘HashNotFoundException’
```

I'm compiling using `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)` on OS X 10.8.5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct BadgerDbException {};
struct PageId {};
struct FrameId {};

struct HashNotFoundException : public BadgerDbException {
  std::string name;
  PageId pageNo;
  HashNotFoundException(const std::string& nameIn, PageId pageNoIn)
    : BadgerDbException(), name(nameIn), pageNo(pageNoIn) {
    }
};

struct HashTable {
  void lookup(void* file, const PageId pageNo, FrameId &frameNo) {
    throw HashNotFoundException("a file", pageNo);
  }
};    

int main() {
  HashTable * hashTable = new HashTable;
  PageId a_Page_ID;
  FrameId dummyFrame;
  try {
    FrameId dummyFrame;
    hashTable->lookup(NULL, a_Page_ID, dummyFrame);
  }
  catch (HashNotFoundException *e) { std::cout<<"HashNotFoundException *"<<std::endl;}
  catch (HashNotFoundException &e) { std::cout<<"HashNotFoundException &"<<std::endl;}
  catch (HashNotFoundException e)  { std::cout<<"HashNotFoundException"<<std::endl; }
  catch (...)                      { std::cout<<"... exception"<<std::endl; }
}
```

Comment: BadgerDBException:) I'm using Apple LLVM compiler 4.2. In essence this is exactly what my code does. The only difference is HashNotFoundException constructor is declared explicit - but from what I have read this shouldn't make a difference...